# Assign form field value to all records in subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm pretty new to Access, so this may be very easy or obvious to some, or maybe it can't be done at all. I have searched this site, but I may not even be using the proper keywords. So far, I haven't found anything that helps me do what I am trying to do.

I have a form with a continuous subform in it. I have an unbound txt field on the main form called txtPO_num. In this form I run a query that displays all records that meet specified criteria in the continuous subform. I also have a control in the subform called PO_Num. My question is, how do I get the main form field value in txtPO_num to populate the PO_Num control in only the records displayed in the subform?

If there is another way to accomplish this I would be interested in knowing that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute an `UPDATE` statement which targets the same records which are included in the subform.

You have a `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause which identifies the records included in the subform's recordset.  Build an `UPDATE` statement using the same `WHERE` clause.  For example, if the `SELECT` were ...

```sql
SELECT field1, field2
FROM YourTable
WHERE field2 = 'foo';
```

... the `UPDATE` could be ...

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET field1 = 'new value'
WHERE field2 = 'foo';
```

Execute the `UPDATE` statement using the DAO database object's `.Execute` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for answereing. I think I get it - using the 2nd approach, this declares the subform control as a variable then loops through it applying the value in the form field to each record until it reaches the end of the recordset. I put the code in the click event of a command button, but I can't get it to work. I think it has something to do with the line !field1 = 'new value', but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put there.

Comment: `RecordsetClone` is read-only, so that suggestion was wrong and I removed it from the answer.