# Subform field update when subID = frmID not targeting correct subform record

Tags: ms-access, vba, subforms

My form contains a combo box where I select a record and it populates `txt` fields in a subform. On the `save` button, I have the following VBA code.

```
Private Sub Save_Record_Click()
    If Forms![frmAccount]![subAcctAppointment].Form![ApptID] = Forms![frmAccount]![subAccount].Form![txtAcctApptID] Then
        Forms![frmAccount]![subAcctAppointment].Form![Added].Value = -1
    End If
End Sub
```

It works if there is only one record in the `subaccount` form, but can't seem the put the check mark (the `-1`) on the following records. Any suggestions?

Comment: VBA that refers to fields on a Form or Subform can only affect the current record. Perhaps this will help: [Assign form field value to all records in subform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445101/assign-form-field-value-to-all-records-in-subform).

Comment: Thanks.  I've moved onto a different approach.